# Guidance on OCR string matching with Sikulix

Tags: excel, automation, ocr, sikuli

I have 2 columns in an excel sheet where column A is a series of questions and column B contains the corresponding answers. Let's pretend that column A asks the age of a certain person and column B provides the answer in a sentence such that "the age of John is 38" etc. These columns will be imported into an app which will be automated via Sikuli. What would be a good way to utilize Sikuli to ensure that when the question from cell A1 is asked, only the answer from cell B1 is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that OCR implementation that is used within Sikuli is not 100% reliable to say the least. Hence it is highly recommended to avoid using it at all costs and try to an alternative solution. For example, in many cases it is possible to select the text and just copy it to your clipboard.

```
type("c", KeyModifier.CTRL)
text = Env.getClipboard()
```

This will obviously give you a 100% correct recognition.

From your question I understand that you are using specific cells A1 and B1? In such case I reckon you definitely can follow the above approach. Just us the excel column and row titles as pivot points and fins the cells you need by offsetting the location by a required number of pixels.

```
pivotPoint = find("excelRowPattern.png")
relativeRegion = Region(pivotPoint.x + xoff, pivotPoint.y + yoff, pivotPoint.w, pivotPoint.h)
```

Then double click on the area and copy the text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Store it an a variable and do the same with the rest of the cells.